# Breadcrumbs - Exclude Child Categories

Tags: functions, navigation

I am using this code in my functions.php file to display breadcrumbs on my web site..

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
            if (!is_home()) {
                    echo '<a href="';
                    echo get_option('home');
                    echo '">';
                    echo 'Home';
                    echo "</a> Â» ";
                    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
                            the_category('title_li=');
                            if (is_single()) {
                                    echo " Â» ";
                                    the_title();
                            }
                    } elseif (is_page()) {
                            echo the_title();
                    }
            }
    }
```

I would like to know how to modify this so that only Parent categories are displayed?  I have lots of posts that are assigned to multiple sub categories so the breadcrumb trail can get huge!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion: [Yoast's SEO plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) is practically a must for a WordPress site, and has a breadcrumb implementation baked in.

Comment: Good call Chris, after trying lots of different solutions none of them were as efficient as Yoasts built in functions so I have gone with that instead.